# Spring multiple ConfigurationProperties for one prefix

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a following structure in my application.yml

```
conf:
  a:
    prop1: abc
    prop2: abc
  b:
    prop3: abc
```

Now I want to have configuration A in one ConfigurationProperties class and configuration B in another. I can do that like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf")
class A{
  Map<String, String> a;
}
```

And another class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf")
class A{
  Map<String, String> b;
}
```

But now I'm getting error saying that prefix is duplicated. Is it possible to have `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf.a")` and `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf.b")` and somehow load all these properties into a map like that?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf.a")
class A{
  Map<String, String> allProperties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do this:

```
conf:
  a:
   config:
    prop1: abc
    prop2: abc
  b:
   config:
    prop3: abc
```

You will then be able to use the prefixes:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf.a")
class A{
  Map<String, String> config;
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conf.b")
class B{
  Map<String, String> config;
}
```